# DisplayAlert() not showing in custom layout

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I implemented my own `WrapLayout` in Xamarin.Forms. Now the `DisplayAlert` in the constructor of the page isn't showing anything.

```
 public WrapLayoutExtendedPage()
 {
       InitializeComponent();

       wrapLayoutExtended.Children.Add(new CustomLabel() { Text = "Label 1 Test", WidthRequest = 500, BackgroundColor = Color.Green, Length = 3 });
       wrapLayoutExtended.Children.Add(new CustomEntry() { WidthRequest = 900, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, Length = 9, InsertBreakAfter = true });

       wrapLayoutExtended.Children.Add(new CustomLabel() { Text = "Label 2 Test", WidthRequest = 500, BackgroundColor = Color.Green, Length = 5 });
       wrapLayoutExtended.Children.Add(new CustomEntry() { WidthRequest = 900, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, Length = 7, InsertBreakAfter = true });

       DisplayAlert("TEST", "TEST", "OK");
}
```

No exception or something. I tried to run it on UI thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     DisplayAlert("TEST", "TEST", "OK");
});
```

It doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think you should create a async method and call it from the Constructor

Comment: @NathielPaulino But why does it work on all other pages I created since now?

Comment: when I want to create a `DisplayAlert` off my current class, I inherit from ContentPage, you have other WrapLayout and works? or just in this specific page?

Comment: Its just this specific page. It's a normal page, deriving from ContentPage like every other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `await` it and should not call in constructor.

Example:

```
public async void OnAppearing()
{
    await DisplayAlert("TEST", "TEST", "OK");
}
```

Comment: I don't even need the await operator. Why does it work in OnAppearing()? Is it running before the page appears if I call it in the constructor?

Comment: @greenhoorn You **do** need the `await` operator even if it works without it. You will get some very strange and hard to track down issues if you do not `await` async methods that return a `Task`